# Null hypothesis for one sample and two proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

Ten people taste wine A and wine B. Let $X$ denote the number who prefer A. Assume that all the others indicate a preference for B. The people are a random sample.

If $X=10$, and we test the null hypothesis of no difference in preference between the wines (vs. two-sided alternative), the $p$-value is equal to 0.0020.

I don't get how one comes to the conclusion that the p-value is 0.0020. Are you supposed to use the one sample test for proportion?

Comment: Almost certainly, though it could also be done with a chi-square test.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use a classical test for proportion. You can use the exact binomial distribution. There are only two values as extreme as $x = 10$, this is $x = 0$ or $10$. Thus

$$\def\P{\mathbb P}
\begin{aligned} p &= \P( X = 0 \text{ or } X = 10)\\
&= \P(X = 0) + \P(X = 10)\\
&= 2\times \P(X = 0)\\
&= 2 \times {10 \choose 0} \times \left(1 \over 2\right)^{10}\\
&= 2 \times 1 \times {1\over 2^{10}}\\
&= {1\over 512}\\
&= 0.0019
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: How do I express this in the normal distribution probability using the z-score? I find that it's easier for me.

Comment: @Sue, is this homework?

Comment: I see that this is now tagged as homework.

Here are a few first hints: what is the distribution of $X$? Its mean? Its variance? You can approximate the distribution of $X$ by a normal distribution: why (criteria), and which one?